# Cannot create Hadoop cluster; bash files not found

Tags: software-installation, hadoop

I have installed **hadoop** inside the `/usr/local/hadoop/bin` directory. When I try executing the bash script `start-all.sh`, the system gives below error:

```
start-all.sh: command not found
```

Furthermore, I don't see any of the following in `usr/local/hadoop/bin`:

- `stopall.sh`
- `start-dfs.sh`
- `stop-dfs.sh`
- `start-all.sh`
- `stop-all.sh`

It doesn't have the `/usr/local/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh` file either, so I created a `hadoop-env.sh` file and set the java home env variable as:

```
The java implementation to use.  Required. 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *hadoop-env.sh*, *stopall.sh*, *start-dfs.sh*, *stop-dfs.sh*, *start-all.sh*, *stop-all.sh* will be in */usr/local/hadoop/conf*.

You don't have to create any configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

you should have all the files if you have installed it correctly.

all the .sh file should be their in hadoop/bin folder.
and under hadoop-env.sh have other important config as well.

i am concerned about the installation can you give me some detail how you installed hadoop, the version and flavor of hadoop.